# Making a hotspot qr code in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

hi guys here is a documentation https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents#wi-fi-network-config-android-ios-11  about making hotspot qr code, I want to make A qr code with WPA/WPA2 encryption , the SSId is always generated new , and password so the ex code should ssid and password should se  dynamiclly .Pls help me to make qr code and a scanner

```
package javaapplication27;
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
public class NewClass1{
        private static final String qcip = "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\anshul\\qrcode.png";
  private static void generateQRCode(String text, int width, int height, String filePath)
            throws Exception {
        QRCodeWriter qcwobj = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix bmobj = qcwobj.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
        Path pobj = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(bmobj, "PNG", pobj);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            generateQRCode("My Name Is anshul",1250, 1250, qcip);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not generate QR Code" + e);
        } 

    }
```

Comment: I have tried to make a qr code of my name, and already went through many site and documentation , but no success in making qr code, I went to many html api but idk how to use them in java code, actually im just 16 and Im learning java and python . pls bro help me @a_local_nobody

Comment: https://qrcode.tec-it.com/en/WiFi        here u can find the api of it. I have made an java code which start hotspot with different password , so i want to get the value of ssid & password from that. this api is of html basically can u guided me how to use in java @a_local_nobody

Comment: thanks bro ....I really appreciate that.